# UpdateInterval not working correctly

Tags: dynamic

I fail to see why the following code does not turn the hand at the same rate as the minute hand of a clock:

```
DynamicModule[{incr, s},
    incr = Pi / (2.0 * 15 * 60);
    s = (Pi / 2.0) + incr;
    Graphics[{
        Circle[],
        Dynamic[
            Refresh[s -= incr; Line[{{0, 0}, {Cos@s, Sin@s}}], UpdateInterval -> 1]
            (*, TrackedSymbols :> {} stops the movement entirely *)
        ]
    }]
]
```

It seems that `UpdateInterval` has no effect. Not matter the value to which it is set, the hand moves at the same speed. And, as indicated in the comment inside the code, setting the `TrackedSymbols` option stops the movement of the hand entirely.

**EDIT**

It turns out that I simply had to quit the notebook and restart that. That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
DynamicModule[{incr, s},
    incr=Pi/(2.0*15*60);
    s=(Pi/2.0)+incr;
    {
        Graphics[
            {
            Circle[],
            Dynamic[
                s-=incr; Line[{{0,0},{Cos@s,Sin@s}}],
                TrackedSymbols->{},
                UpdateInterval->1
            ]
            }
        ],
        Dynamic[s]
    }
]
```

Comment: I have copy-pasted your code, and it does not work for me. The `TrackedSymbols` line stops any movement. Its removal brings back the same behaviour as before (i.e. as the original code). (Windows 10 Professional 64-bit, Mathematica 11.3, all the latest updates applied.)

Comment: @Shredderroy What Mathematica version?

Comment: Version 11.3. I was a little late to anticipate that question, but I have added the information to my previous comment as an edit.

Comment: Does `DynamicModule[{x}, 
 Dynamic[x++, TrackedSymbols -> {}, UpdateInterval -> 1], 
 Initialization :> (x = 0)]` work for you?

Comment: It just shows `0`. There is no updating of the value. Can you please tell me what OS you are using? It should not matter, but I am curious if the OS has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: @Shredderroy I'm using MacOS. The above DynamicModule code is from the documentation for UpdateInterval. Maybe you can try the code again after restarting Mathematica from a new notebook.

Comment: Alright! That was it. I had to quit the notebook and restart it. Thank you! I will accept your answer.